# How do i send email to outlook 2010 in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to send email with outlook despite my server doesnt install outlook 2010 and its within the intranet zone? Because everyone here communicate with outlook and had a unique outlook account. How can i send email from my application? I am pretty sure i cannt use the following code to solve my problem, someone please help me.

code:

```
// Create the Outlook application.
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
// Create a new mail item.
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
// Set HTMLBody. 
//add the body of the email
oMsg.HTMLBody = body;
//Add an attachment.
//String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
///int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
//int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
//now attached the file
//Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\fileName.jpg", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

//Subject line
oMsg.Subject = subject;
// Add a recipient.
Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
// Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(address);
oRecip.Resolve();
// Send.
oMsg.Send();
// Clean up.
oRecip = null;
oRecips = null;
oMsg = null;
oApp = null;
```

Comment: Did any answer help you out? Please mark as answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is an example snippet I used in a project of mine:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

private void SendMail( string targetMail, 
                       string shownTargetName, 
                       string[] attachmentNames) {
  var fromAddress = new MailAddress("support@infinibrain.net", "MailSendingProgram");
  var toAddress = new MailAddress(targetMail, shownTargetName);
  const string fromPassword = "12345isAbadPassword";
  subject = "Your Subject";
  body = 
        @"
          Here
          you can put in any text
          that will appear in the body
        ";
  var smtp = new SmtpClient {
    Host = "smtp.mailserver.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
  };

  using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress) {
                             Subject = subject,
                             Body = body }
        ) {
    foreach(string filePath in attachmentNames[]) {
      Attachment attachMail = new Attachment(filePath);
      message.Attachments.Add(attachMail);
    }

    try {
      smtp.Send(message);
      MessageBox.Show("E-Mail sent!");
    } catch {
      MessageBox.Show("Sending failed, check your internet connection!");
    }
  }
}
```

In this example I included everything required to use file attachments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send email you didn't need outlook you need email adres, for example

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = ""; // put the from address here
mail.To = ""; // put to address here
mail.Subject = ""; // put subject here
mail.Body = ""; // put body of email here
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = ""; // put smtp server you will use here
// and then send the mail
SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

and read this [Send email](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/)

**EDIT**

But if you want to use OUTLOOK try this

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                    Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
                    email.Recipients.Add("EmailAddress@google.com");
                    email.Subject = "Subject";
                    email.Body = "Message";


                    ((Outlook.MailItem)email).Send();
```

**EDIT2**

Example of first code

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");//who send
mm.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("Yourmail@gmail.com"));//where send
mm.Subject = "Subj";
mm.Body = "text";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: I have COM Exception..does it mean that any address will work in your code?

Comment: both, but first gives me a connection error, says it could not connect to the server..

Comment: @HuatsinYeo You need to read this for use edit part http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/casperboekhoudt/SendingEmailsThroughOutlook12052005000124AM/SendingEmailsThroughOutlook.aspx

Comment: @HuatsinYeo and i need to see exeption, for help

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net you can also send email through user's outlook using script manager:

```
//add this to your page body (or in master page body)
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>

//add this to your SendEmailButton_Click() event
string email = "mailto:recipient@domain.com?subject=my subject&body=my message.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("document.location.href='" + email + "';");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "sendemail", sb.ToString(), true);
```